# str_replace() on unescaped Laravel Blade variable

Tags: php, html, xml, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm creating a XML file and have this code:

```
<ENTRY>{!! $html !!}</ENTRY>
```

The result, in the XML file can be something like this:

```
<ENTRY><b>20&#09;</b><b>LISA & PETER</ENTRY>
```

What I want is to parse somehow this $html to convert all `&` to `&amp;` to get this result:

```
<ENTRY><b>20&#09;</b><b>LISA &amp; PETER</ENTRY>
```

If I do a str_replace() before the {!! !!}, it will convert anyway the replaced to an `&`.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. Are you sure you're not looking at the output in a browser, which is *displaying* the same thing for `&` and `&amp;` (just as this question did before I edited it)?

Comment: correct. I'm not displaying that output in the browser, but exporting a xml file. 
This file is later processed in Adobe InDesign.